# Использование ROW_NUMBER() при группировке PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Новенький в SQL, подскажите, как правильно использовать функцию `ROW_NUMBER()`, если в запросе уже присутствует `GROUP BY`.

Приведу пример:

Я пытаюсь обновить поле `achievements` у сотрудников, кто совершил больше всех продаж.
В `achievements` должно появиться -- Работник ТОП-1 или Работник ТОП-2 в зависимости от места в топе.

```
    SELECT  order_tab.employee_id,
              SUM(order_item.price * order_item.quantity) AS total_sum,
              COUNT(order_tab.order_id) AS total_clients,
              row_number() over (PARTITION BY employee_id) AS number
    FROM order_tab
             JOIN order_item ON order_tab.order_id = order_item.order_id
    GROUP BY order_tab.employee_id
    ORDER BY total_sum DESC, total_clients DESC
    LIMIT 3;

    UPDATE employee SET achievements = concat_ws(', ', achievements, 'Работник ТОП-', number, ' за месяц')
    WHERE employee.employee_id IN ( SELECT  employee_id
                                    FROM    best_employees);
```

Но во-первых UPDATE не видит поле number из запроса. А во-вторых row_number не выводит то, что нужно

Нужно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть просто порядковый номер

Comment: Возможно стоит использовать просто инкремент. переменную в UPDATE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with best_employees as (
    SELECT  order_tab.employee_id,
              SUM(order_item.price * order_item.quantity) AS total_sum,
            COUNT(order_tab.order_id) AS total_clients
    FROM order_tab
             JOIN order_item ON order_tab.order_id = order_item.order_id
    GROUP BY order_tab.employee_id
    ORDER BY total_sum DESC, total_clients DESC
    LIMIT 3
)
UPDATE employee 
SET achievements = concat_ws(
      ', ', 
      achievements, 
      'Работник ТОП-'||row_number() over (order by total_sum desc, total_clients desc)||' за месяц'
    )
from best_employees
WHERE employee.employee_id = best_employees.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы уже всё сгруппировали, то вам просто нужна последовательная сквозная нумерация сгруппированных строк с учетом сортировки:

```sql
row_number() over (ORDER BY total_sum DESC, total_clients DESC) AS number
```

Comment: `row_number` и `group by` вместе работают нет так, как ты ожидаешь.